# Having trouble parsing these data in watir-webdriver

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, watir, watir-webdriver

See hierarchy below:

[image]

All I need here is "Company Title", "Company Owner", "Company Owner Title", "Street Number Street Name", and "City, State Zipcode".

I tried `b.div.span.bs`, but that didn't work (`bs` because there are multiple blocks I'm gathering data from). I also thought I'd just try something like `b.tds.split('<br>')` and then replace all instances of tags and somehow delete empty array cells, but I found that each block is different, so the data don't align, i.e., Company Title might be in cell 1 for the first array, but then if Company Title isn't present (for the second block) then cell 1 would be Company Owner, which is conflicting... Anyway, just trying to find a clever way to get these data. Thank you.

[Here](http://www.shoutkey.com/least) is the actual HTML; however **you must first click "View All".**

Comment: I think the answer will depend on how the data can vary. Can you show what the different variations that the blocks can be? You mention that the company title might not be present, but it is hard to tell what that exactly means in terms of the HTML layout. Which other fields might be optional? (It would also help if you could paste the HTML as opposed to a screenshot - this makes it easier for us to copy and verify solutions.)

Comment: @JustinKo, let me check.

Comment: Can you give us a link to one of the pages? That would go a long way in helping us to come up with a solution that would work consistently.

Comment: https://postimg.org/gallery/2bdrpopdc/01c6fffe/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[mcve]". We need the minimum sample HTML as text in the question, not as an image. We also need the minimum code you wrote that demonstrates the problem. Without that we'd either have to write a tutorial, with is off-topic because your question is too broad. Without the HTML as text we have to type it in, or we have to extract it from whatever site you got it from, which wastes our time trying to help you. So, help us help you.

Comment: That HTML needs to be reduced to the minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem and then put into the question itself. Asking us to go to a page and sift through it wastes our time. We expect you to put in that effort if you want us to put in our effort.

Comment: @theTinMan, that's what the screenshot was for. So... you want a text-version of the screenshot is what you're saying?

Comment: Screenshots are lazy? What must I do to appease?

Comment: Screenshots of text are frowned upon on SO. Ideally you would post the HTML as text. It's easier for readers to grab the text and use it, if needed, which makes people more likely to help answer the question. Screenshots are better used for pictures of the UI, etc.

Comment: Screen shots of data, especially input data, are lazy. They're convenient for you but very inconvenient for anyone trying to help you, because we invariably need to recreate that just to test the code you submitted plus test our answers. Remember, you're asking us to help you for free, so it's only fair you do you part and make it as easy as possible for us.

Answer (score 1):

You can split out everything inside the `<div>` and then split that by `<br>`. The first part is Company Title (if exists) and then Company Owner is last/second.

The rest is ... trickier. Some are pretty straighforward in that Fax and Member Since have labels so those are easy. The `<a>` is easy.

You could probably test the phone number with a regex and then back up from there. If the one before the phone number isn't `<a>` then it's city, state zip and the one before that is the address. If one exists before that, it's the Company Owner Title.

Everything after the phone number in your examples have labels so those are easy.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure all of your use cases, but often for pages where the DOM is not very helpful I just get the text and parse with Ruby:

```
browser.td.text.split("\n").reject(&:empty?)
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't directly answer the question, but it shows how I'd go about doing this using Nokogiri, which is the standard HTML/XML parser for Ruby:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML('<td><div></div><br>a<br>b<br>c</td>')
```

`doc` is Nokogiri's internal representation of the document.

We use landmarks in the markup to navigate and find things we want. In this case `<div>` is a good starting point:

```
doc.at('div').next_sibling.next_sibling.text # => "a"
```

`next_sibling` is how we tell Nokogiri to look at the next node. In this case it's stepping past the first `<br>` and looking at the `a` TextNode.

That'd result in unworkable code though, so there's a better way to go:

```
doc.search('td br').to_html # => "<br><br><br>"
```

That shows we can find all the `<br>` tags inside the `<td>`, so we just have to iterate over them and use them as our landmarks:

```
doc.search('td br').map{ |br| br.next_sibling.text } # => ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Comment: Received error upon install: `ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
    Operation not permitted - /usr/bin/nokogiri`

Comment: This is what I ran: `sudo gem install nokogiri`

Comment: I don't know enough about your system to help based on that little bit of information. Also, that'd be a separate question. Installing Nokogiri is covered well on the site.